# Laravel actingAs guest

Tags: laravel, authentication, testing

Laravel provides a way to [authenticate a given user during HTTP testing](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication) with

```
$this->actingAs($user);
```

Is there a way to unauthenticate that `$user` within the same test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can unauthenticate using this:

```
Auth::logout();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#logging-out

> **Warning:** above does far more than just forgetting (**acting** as if the login did not happen), for example, when using JWT above should invalidate token.

Comment: This is not working in Laravel 9. $this->assertGuest() returns "The user is authenticated
  Failed asserting that true is false." even after using the logout-method.

Comment: @NKnuelle The following works for me:

`$this->post('/logout');`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, define new `actingAsGuest` method in base `TestCase` class
in file `tests/TestCase.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // add logout method to RequestGuard
        RequestGuard::macro('logout', function() {
            $this->user = null;
        });
    }

    // add method to base TestCase class
    public function actingAsGuest(): void
    {
        $this->app['auth']->logout();
    }
}
```

And then in your test class you can use it:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {
        // acting as authenticated user
        $this->actingAs(User::factory()->create());
        $this->assertAuthenticated();
        
        // acting as unauthenticated user
        $this->actingAsGuest();
        $this->assertGuest();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working in Laravel 9. Even after using the actingAsGuest-method the test is unsuccessful: The user is authenticated.  Failed asserting that true is false.

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirements as OP did, but wanted `actingAsGuest()` to completely reset everything, except Database state.

## Full App reset <sup>(except DB)</sup>

### For Laravel 7 <sup>(and maybe newer or older)</sup>

I toke a look at Laravel's `tearDown()` and `setUp()` methods.

And came up with helper method like:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

// ...

function actingAsGuest()
{
    // Backup database state.
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection $connection */
    $connection = app('db.connection');

    // Reset everything else.
    /** @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app */
    $app = $this->app;
    $app->flush();
    $this->app = null;
    Facade::clearResolvedInstances();
    $this->refreshApplication();

    // Restore database state.
    app('db')->extend($connection->getName(), function () use ($connection) {
        return $connection;
    });
}
```

#### WARNING !!

Above works fine unless your test's logic caches any of above discarded objects somewhere.

For example, Laravel's `DatabaseTransactions` trait did cache `db` facade (in their App-Destroyed-listener).

Which we fixed by overriding said trait's logic.

> Like we changed:
>
> ```
> // ...
>
> $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () use ($database) {
>
>    // ...
> ```
>
> Into:
>
> ```
> // ...
>
> $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
>    $database = app('db');
>
>    // ...
> ```